# Cordova Visual studio - onload functions & sms inbox startwatch

Tags: jquery, cordova

I´m having a problem obtaining the SMS list because the `onWatch` function is not working.

This is the plugin i´m using:
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms

```
function theStarter() {
    startW();
    triggerEventSMS();
    window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake();
}
window.onload = theStarter;

function triggerEventSMS() {
    window.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function (e) {
        alert("new sms inbox");
    });
}
function startW() {
        SMS.startWatch(function () {
            update('watching', 'watching started');
        }, function () {
            updateStatus('failed to start watching');
        });
}
```

The `keepAwake` function is also not working 100% of the time, I guess this happen because `ons.bootstrap();`

It works on new phones, not in a 4.0.4 and on a xiaomi 2sim 4.4.
My sdk settings are recomended sdk 22.

Thank you.